# Generate High Quality PDF with Javascript (jspdf+html2canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf, html2canvas

I've been trying to convert and generate PDF from HTML page with click of a button on the page that automatically generates and force download a PDF of the page using two popular addons
* JSPDF
* HTML2Canvas
So far everything works fine but the PDF generated are always blurry and not high quality 
after importing the js files (jquery, html2canvas, jspdf). Here is my javascript code

```js
function CreatePDFfromHTML() {
    var HTML_Width = $(".html-content").width();
    var HTML_Height = $(".html-content").height();
    var top_left_margin = 15;
    var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
    var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

    var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;

    html2canvas($(".html-content")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
        for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) { 
            pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
        }
        pdf.save("invoice_<?php echo $trackingNumber ;?>.pdf");
        $(".html-content").hide();
    });
}
```

How do i adjust the code to make html2canvas convert the page to a better quality image (get rid of the blur and make the PDF file generated even better)

Comment: Why are you not using jspdf alone?

Comment: because it doesn't do very well with css stylings so i had to convert pae to Image with html2cavas and then to pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of searching i finally found a way to make the quality better by multiplying the `HTML_Width` and `HTML_height` by factor of 3. Here is the new code:

```js
function CreatePDFfromHTML() {
    var HTML_Width = $(".html-content").width()*3;
    var HTML_Height = $(".html-content").height()*3;
    var top_left_margin = 15;
    var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
    var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

    var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;

    html2canvas($(".html-content")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
        for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) { 
            pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
        }
        pdf.save("invoice_<?php echo $trackingNumber ;?>.pdf");
        $(".html-content").hide();
    });
}
```