# jsPDF html2Canvas producing a low quality image to PDF using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I want to print some HTML to an PDF and am using a combination of html2Canvas and jsPDF to achieve that.

It all works just fine, however, the image quality is quite poor and doesn't look very sharp.

I've done some research but haven't found a solution that actually improves the quality of the image. Any suggestions would be well appreciated.

```
    function printPDF() {
        const domElement = document.getElementById("print-pdf");
        html2canvas(domElement, {
            onclone: (document) => {
                document.getElementById("print-button");
            },
        }).then((canvas) => {
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image.png", 1.0);
            const doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 5, 5);
            doc.save(`${leadData.company}-Timo-Huennebeck-Cover-Letter`);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does changing the compression value make a difference? See documentation: [addImage](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage)

Comment: That was a good suggestion I hadn't thought of before but unfortunately it's still the same.

Comment: Related question: [Generate High Quality PDF with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60933665/generate-high-quality-pdf-with-javascript-jspdfhtml2canvas) and other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjspdf%5D+image+quality) which might help.